# Is it possible to use Symfony2/Doctrine form validation without a relational database?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following controller action (much simplified):

```
public function createAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $form = $this->createForm(
        new DashboardType(),
        new Dashboard()
    );

    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
                       ->getManager();
            $dm->persist($dashboard);
            $dm->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

Where dashboard is a Mongo Document object rather than an Entity. This code fails on the $form->bind line with the following DBAL error:

```
PDOException: could not find driver
```

I'm assuming this is due to the fact I don't have a relational database set up in my parameters.yml file. All I need for this app is Mongo which is run via Docker.

Is it possible to run Symfony and Doctrine with features like form validation if no database is installed? It seems a bit pointless to have to dockerise and manage a MySQL instance that won't be used purely to satisfy the Symfony requirements.

Is there a way around this?

**Update**

This isn't a driver issue as I can read and write fine to Mongo without form valiation. Edited response from modules:

```
$ php -m

[PHP Modules]
mongo
PDO
```

**Solution**

By default, Symfony adds the following to your config.yml

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   "%database_driver%"
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #     path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        auto_mapping: true
```

This somehow affects the form validators. By deleting that section and just having the doctrine mongo config, the errors are fixed.

Comment: the symfony2 validation component is independent of the database schema. The error message is about missing php mongo driver

Comment: The driver is fine as I can read and write to Mongo without the form validation component. The problem only occurs when I try and combine it with forms. Updated the question to show modules output.

Comment: Bit off topic but assuming you are using S2.1+ then you can simplify your form handling code a bit and avoid using some depreciated methods.  http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#handling-form-submissions

Answer (score 1):

You should configure Symfony to use MongoDB as persistence system.

You can find the setup process on the DoctrineMongoDBBundle of the Symfony doc :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/index.html

Comment: That is exactly how I've set it up and it works fine. The error only occurs when binding request objects to document-based forms.

Comment: How your configuration file looks like ?

Comment: Ah, I just fixed it. It was due to Symfony adding a default Doctrine DBAL section in config.yml which wasn't needed and was somehow being referenced in the form validation. After deleting the whole section everything started working. Cheers for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: cool, pls set your question as closed, thanks and happy new year!